# Resilience issues of relying on jQuery, Bootstrap, etc

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

As I build and maintain a few websites, I am often led towards solutions using jQuery, Bootstrap, etc. I hesitate and try to work around relying on these libraries, etc.

My concern is I may be building in more potential causes of failure. What if (say) maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com goes down? What if they bring out Bootstrap 5 and it breaks something I've done? On the other hand, these tools do offer neat solutions to site building issues.

I've searched and no one else seems to have these concerns. Am I missing something here?  Is there some guidance on whether to rely on these tools?

Comment: You don't need to use their CDN, you can download jQuery and bootstrap and host them on your server.

Answer (score 0):

> My concern is I may be building in more potential causes of failure.

There are always pros and cons to a situation, you just have to pick what is more important.  (I'll play devils advocate to your concerns)

> What if (say) maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com goes down?

[Build in as many backup CDNs as you want](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx).

> What if they bring out Bootstrap 5 and it breaks something I've done?

That is guaranteed to happen.  The question is *is building my own bootstrap less expensive than upgrading to the next version*.  Inevitability the cost of maintaining your own and changing it with newer technology is always **more** expensive then using open source/free tools that thousands if not millions of people help build and test.

> On the other hand, these tools do offer neat solutions to site building issues.

Usually you'll find they match between 75 and 99% of what you need them to do, and when they don't you either have to do a bit of extra work or find another solution/framework to add on.